# grouping a list values based on max value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm working on k-mean algorthim to cluster list of number, If i have an array (X)

```
X=array([[0.85142858],[0.85566274],[0.85364912],[0.81536489],[0.84929932],[0.85042336],[0.84899714],[0.82019115], [0.86112067],[0.8312496 ]])
```

then I run the following code

```
from sklearn.cluster import AgglomerativeClustering

cluster = AgglomerativeClustering(n_clusters=5, affinity='euclidean', linkage='ward')
cluster.fit_predict(X)

for i in range(len(X)):
    print("%4d " % cluster.labels_[i], end=""); print(X[i])
```

i  got the results

```
   1     1  [0.85142858]
   2     3  [0.85566274]
   3     3  [0.85364912]
   4     0  [0.81536489]
   5     1  [0.84929932]
   6     1  [0.85042336]
   7     1  [0.84899714]
   8     0  [0.82019115]
   9     4  [0.86112067]
   10    2  [0.8312496]
```

how to get the max number in each cluster  with value of (i) ? like this

```
0: 0.82019115   8
1: 0.85142858   1
2: 0.8312496    10
3: 0.85566274   2
4: 0.86112067   9
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First group them together as pair using `zip` then sort it by values(second element of pair) in increasing order and create a dict out of it.

Try:

```
res =  list(zip(cluster.labels_, X))
max_num = dict(sorted(res, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=False))
```

**max_num:**

```
{0: array([0.82019115]),
 2: array([0.8312496]),
 1: array([0.85142858]),
 3: array([0.85566274]),
 4: array([0.86112067])}
```

**Edit:**

Do you want this?

```
elem = list(zip(res, range(1,len(X)+1)))
e = sorted(elem, key=lambda x: x[0][1], reverse=False)
final_dict = {k[0]:(k[1], v) for (k,v) in e}
for key in sorted(final_dict):
    print(f"{key}: {final_dict[key][0][0]} {final_dict[key][1]}")
```

---

```
0: 0.82019115 8
1: 0.85142858 1
2: 0.8312496 10
3: 0.85566274 2
4: 0.86112067 9
```

## OR

```
import pandas as pd    
df = pd.DataFrame(zip(cluster.labels_,X))
df[1] = df[1].str[0]
df = df.sort_values(1).drop_duplicates([0],keep='last')
df.index = df.index+1
df = df.sort_values(0)
```

---

**df:**

```
    0   1
8   0   0.820191
1   1   0.851429
10  2   0.831250
2   3   0.855663
9   4   0.861121
```

Comment: Pygirl thank you but i need to print (i) in same line

Comment: Pygirl  thank you very much for your help, but why value of (i) increased by 1, for example for cluster 0, it return 0: [0.82019115] 8 which should return 0: [0.82019115] 7 ?  and the order is 0,2,1,3,4 ??? why not 0,1,2,3,4 ? thanks in advance

Comment: because you wanted index to be start from 1 not from zero. That's why. Check my edited answer.  I have reordered them by keys. If you want index to start from zero only. Then remove increment by 1 and in range start with 0.

Comment: `for example for cluster 0, it return 0: [0.82019115] 8 which should return 0: [0.82019115] 7 ? ` You yourself have mentioned in the question that your index will look like that which is incremented by 1 as they start from 1 not from zero.

Comment: Can you close the question?